# Umbraco 7, How to change a custom property in MemberService.Saved

Tags: c#, .net, umbraco, umbraco7

I am struggling with changing a simple true / false flag in member properties once the Is Approved flag is set to true for the first time. I can change the property but the value is not saved / committed. I have tried both  MemberService.Saved and  MemberService.Saving. I am quite new to Umbraco so may have missed something obvious.

```
protected override void ApplicationStarted(UmbracoApplicationBase umbracoApplication, ApplicationContext applicationContext)
{
    MemberService.Saved += MemberService_Saved;
}

void MemberService_Saved(IMemberService sender, Umbraco.Core.Events.SaveEventArgs<IMember> e)
{ 
    foreach (var member in e.SavedEntities)
    {
        if (!member.IsNewEntity())
        {
            var dirtyProperties = member.Properties.Where(x => x.WasDirty()).Select(p => p.Alias);
            if (dirtyProperties.Contains("umbracoMemberApproved"))
            {
                if (member.IsApproved && !member.GetValue<bool>("approvalEmailSent"))
                {
                    //Send Email to Customer
                    //new SmtpClient().Send(mail);

                    var prop = member.Properties["approvalEmailSent"];
                    prop.Value = true;

                    var propValue = member.GetValue<bool>("approvalEmailSent");
                    //Have verified propValue is now true

                    sender.Save(member);
                } 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Strangely I can find another member, make the property change and save it fine, just not the member sent through in e.SavedEntities.

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to me to be some sort of bug, after much debugging I have found the following:

- Even when setting the raise events flag to false on the save, it still comes back through the method again.
- On the second pass through you must set the value of the property you are changing again, even though it should already be saved / committed. I did not need to save again. **I believe this is a bug**
- The original changed by the user property's was dirty flag is no longer set the second time through. So the original check for this was stopping the property I want to change being set again.
- I had to have the was dirty check so that on the second pass through I did not send the email again.
- As a note even changing something unrelated in a member using the umbraco front end will cause my method to run twice.

```
protected override void ApplicationStarted(UmbracoApplicationBase umbracoApplication, ApplicationContext applicationContext)
{
    MemberService.Saved += MemberService_Saved;
}

void MemberService_Saved(IMemberService sender, Umbraco.Core.Events.SaveEventArgs<IMember> e)
{
    foreach (var member in e.SavedEntities)
    {
        if (!member.IsNewEntity())
        {
            if (member.IsApproved && !member.GetValue<bool>("approvalEmailSent"))
            {
                member.SetValue("approvalEmailSent", true);

                var dirtyProperties = member.Properties.Where(x => x.WasDirty()).Select(p => p.Alias);
                if (dirtyProperties.Contains("umbracoMemberApproved"))
                {
                    //Email Customer
                    //new SmtpClient().Send(mail);

                    sender.Save(member, false);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure sounds a bit strange! If you think you've found a bug, consider reporting it here: https://github.com/umbraco/Umbraco-CMS/issues

Answer (score 3):

Maybe try doing this instead?

```
member.SetValue("approvalEmailSent", true);
sender.Save(member, false);
```

When in MemberService.Saved, tell the .Save method to not raise any further events, just to make sure no infinite loops will happen.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that is exactly how I did it the first time I tried this. I just tried again and still not working. I am wondering if there is some kind of security setting somewhere stopping me from doing this.